# Weird rendering of font Helvetica in Chrome

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, google-chrome, fonts, rendering

It started happening after I installed the Helvetica font on my system (at least I think that was the trigger).

I tried to install Helvetica on my Ubuntu 12.10 system but the font viewer crashed when I clicked install.
And since then all sans serif fonts are rendered like this in Chrome and Firefox:

[image]

I was able to replicate the issue in LibreOffice earlier by switching to the Helvetica font.  But currently I'm not able to reproduce it anymore. I also can't find the font under the normal directories to remove or delete it.

It seems it only happens when it's trying to render the Helvetica font family, but no Arial or any others

I've also already cleared the font cache

Answer (score 2):

The font you are linking to looks like [OpenDyslexic](http://dyslexicfonts.com/). Have you installed that font?

In any case, try refreshing your font cache:

```
fc-cache -f -v
```

Comment: I've already cleared the font cache and I haven't installed any fonts other than Helvetica onto my system

Comment: Does this also happen if you log in as a different user? How about after reinstalling some font packages (`sudo apt-get purge msttcorefonts; sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts`)?

Comment: I solved it by putting a truetype file with the same name into the proper directory, clearing the cache, and then deleting it and clearing the cache again, i guess it just overwrote the previous system entry for the helvetica font or something